# TypeError when concatenating django.test.LiveServerTestCase's live_server_url with another string

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-tests

Whenever I try to construct a string based on **`self.live_server_url`**, I get python `TypeError` messages.  For example, I've tried the following string constructions (form 1 & 2 below), but I experience the same `TypeError`.  My desired string is the Live Server URL with `"/lists"` appended.  NOTE: the actual test does succeed to create a server and I can manually access the server, and more specifically, I can manually access the exact URL that I'm trying to build programmatically (e.g. `'http://localhost:8081/lists`').

`TypeError`s occur with these string constructions.

```
# FORM 1
lists_live_server_url = '%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/lists')

# FORM 2
lists_live_server_url = '{0}{1}'.format(self.live_server_url, '/lists')

self.browser.get(lists_live_server_url)
```

There is no python error with this form (nothing appended to string), albeit my test fails (as I would expect since it isn't accessing `/lists`).

```
self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
```

Here is the python error that I'm getting.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py test functional_tests.lists_tests.LiveNewVisitorTest.test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later /Users/myusername/PycharmProjects/mysite_proj
    Testing started at 11:55 AM ...
    Creating test database for alias 'default'...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
        self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1104, in __call__
        return super(FSFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
        response = self.get_response(request)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1087, in get_response
        return self.serve(request)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1099, in serve
        return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 54, in serve
        fullpath = os.path.join(document_root, newpath)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/posixpath.py", line 82, in join
        path += b
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Am I unknowingly attempting to modify the `live_server_url`, which is leading to these `TypeError`s?  How could I programmatically build a string of `live_server_url + "/lists"`?

Here is the test that I am attempting...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class LiveNewVisitorTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.close()

    def test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later(self):
        #self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/lists')
        #self.browser.get('http://www.google.com')
        #lists_live_server_url = '%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/lists')
        #lists_live_server_url = '{0}{1}'.format(self.live_server_url, '/lists')
        lists_live_server_url = self.live_server_url
        self.browser.get(lists_live_server_url)

        self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)
        header_text = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text
        self.assertIn('To-Do', header_text)
```

Comment: Could you please post actual test listing? Not entire test module f course, but at least a setUp, setUpClass (if exists) and the test method that fails?

Comment: Strangely, I was battling with this exact same error last night, but when I tried to come up with a reproducible example to post on StackOverflow I was not able to replicate this TypeError. Did you figure out the root cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See this discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/2w41t0/tdd_with_python_chapter_7_errors_when_adding/) featuring the same error `Traceback`.

Basically, this is not a problem with anything within the `Selenium` tests but rather with your project's static file configuration.

From your question, I believe the key line within the `Traceback` is:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 54, in serve
    fullpath = os.path.join(document_root, newpath)
```

This line indicates that an unsuccessful `os.path.join` is being attempted within `django.views.static`.

Set `STATIC_ROOT` in your project's `settings.py`file and you should be good.

Comment: Verified!  Good find sir. Thank you.

Comment: The strangest part was that I thought, just like you did, that there was something wrong in my concatenation of `self.live_server_url` and various url patterns...

Answer (score 1):

Use StaticLiveServerTestCase instead may help

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may be correct or useful to future readers of this question, you should add some more details in order to make your answer clearer.